# How to add webwork action to a project panel?

Tags: java, plugins, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have made my own plugins (separate) with webwork actions and with project tab modules. But now I need to combine both: there will be some comboboxes and a button that make the plugin calculate statistics. I need to show it in the same project tab.

I am having trouble with both steps:

1. How to do any Java code BEFORE project tab will be shown, and generate contents of this page with info that Java code will retrieve from userManager, groupManager etc. (fill combobox with usernames).
2. How to output new info on the same page after user presses the "Calculate!" button (calculated stats for selected user).

I think I need to redefine some methods on my project panel tab (something like "renderPage").

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Comment: @double-beep, thanks for advice on these questions asked almost 6 years ago :)

Comment: Ok, if possible [edit] your question, else it will be closed as off-topic and deleted

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to edit it, it's too old and I don't even remember asking it, also it's not my field of knowledge anymore. I see that there's an accepted answer with a couple of votes if that's doesn't concern you, please, feel free to close and delete it. On the side note, it seems weird to me that the question was "on-topic" for 5.5 years and then suddenly became "off-topic".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To your first question:

have a look at: [Project Tab Panel Module](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Project+Tab+Panel+Plugin+Module)

the class you have to set there is responsible for rendering the project tab panel. in normal cases you render some velocity templates there. have look at one of the interfaces VersionsProjectTabPanel implements ([com.atlassian.jira.plugin.browsepanel.TabPanel](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/4.3.4/reference/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/browsepanel/TabPanel.html)). there you will find a method named [getHtml(...)](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/4.3.4/reference/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/browsepanel/TabPanel.html#getHtml%28C%29). Jira will call this Method before the Panel is displayed in the web page.

So what you would have to do:

1. define a class that implements the [TabPanel](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/4.3.4/reference/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/browsepanel/TabPanel.html) interface AND set this class in the project tab panel module descriptor in your atlassian-plugin.xml
2. overwrite the method [getHtml(...)](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/4.3.4/reference/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/browsepanel/TabPanel.html#getHtml%28C%29) with your own template rendering process
3. in your overwritten method you have to get a reference to the [VelocityManager](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-velocity/0.1.9/com/atlassian/velocity/VelocityManager.html):

   `VelocityManager velocityManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getVelocityManager();`
4. Write velocity template and render it with [getBody(...)](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-velocity/0.1.9/com/atlassian/velocity/VelocityManager.html#getBody%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) Method:

   `String renderedText = velocityManager.getBody("<PATH_TO_TEMPLATE>", "templatename.vm", context);`
5. If you want to pass content to that template, do that via the context variable of the [getBody(...)](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-velocity/0.1.9/com/atlassian/velocity/VelocityManager.html#getBody%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) Method. The Map is of type `Map<Object, Object>`. Usually you will put in there a String/Object Entry. The Key-String will be declared as variable in the template and the Value-Object is the value of the variable: `Map<String, Object>`
6. give that *renderedText* as return-Value to the caller of [getHtml(...)](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/4.3.4/reference/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/browsepanel/TabPanel.html#getHtml%28C%29) and it will be displayed on the page.

Some Q&A and tutorial pages to that topic:

- [Use Velocity Template in Jira Plugin](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/61075/use-velocity-template-in-jira-plugin)
- [Velocity Templates](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Velocity+Templates)

### To your second question:

Just declare a `<form>...</form>` tag in your velocity template. The action-attribute in there should point to your webwork action url. In the [getHtml(...)](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/4.3.4/reference/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/browsepanel/TabPanel.html#getHtml%28C%29) Method you have overwritten, you have to access the [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) context via [ServletActionContext](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.html):

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
String someRequestParam = request.getParameter("paramName");
```

Pass the request param content to your velocity template via template context map we spoke before or do some business logic with it.