# Displaying filtered issues in JIRA project tab

Tags: jira-plugin

This is my first attempt to create a JIRA plugin and I'm completely lost.

I have already managed to create a project tab plugin. However, I can't find the way to populate the screen with any more than HTML.

My main goal is to display a list of filtered issues in the project tab. I saw the issues list displayed in the Versions tab (screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/0g1O3v0M0p38/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-25%20at%203.49.35%20PM.png) and I figured I could copy the code that did that on a project tab. However I can't find the code that does this.

Any pointers you can give me would be highly appreciated.

TL;DR: Need to know how to filter issues and display them in a project tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) how to filter issues 
Please look here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/__Searching+in+JIRA

2) display them in a project tab.
Here is the answer: [JIRA Plugins - How to add webwork action to a project panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594894/jira-plugins-how-to-add-webwork-action-to-a-project-panel)